# Number of lattice points in a structural symmetric convex body

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, lattices

Let $f$ is a convex symmetric function on the interval $[-a,a]$, i.e., $f(-x)=f(x)$ for $\forall \, x\in [-a,a]$. Then we consider a $n$-dimensional convex body in Euclidean space
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{R}_n=\left\{ \mathbf{x}=\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n \right)\in \mathbb{R}^n： \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \le n\mathsf{A}   \right\},
\end{equation}
where the constant $\mathsf{A}>f(0)$. Clearly, $\mathscr{R}_n$ is symmetric about the origin.
I am interested the following problem relating to the **lower bound** of numbers of the lattice points inside $\mathscr{R}_n$:

Does there exit a lattice sequence $\left\{ \Lambda_n \right\}$ (the minimum distance of $ \Lambda_n$ is $\sqrt{n}$) such that the number sequence $\{N(n)\}$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
N(n)=\frac{\log \left( |\Lambda_n \cap \mathscr{R}_n| \right)}{n}\ge c, ~\text{for sufficiently large $n$.}
\end{equation}
I also want to know if there exits a best lowerbound $c$ for this asymptotic problem.

---

This problem is motivated by the answer of [Geometry interpretation of any continuous random variable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381599/geometry-interpretation-of-any-continuous-random-variable)

Comment: A wrong condition has been fixed.

Comment: Where did the problem arise? Why are you applying log-concave measure to the lattice sequence?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to say “let $g$ be a symmetric concave function”, and replace all instances of $\log f$ with $g$? The question never seems to use $f$ by itself.

Comment: @MattF. You are right. I have edited it according to your comment.

Comment: @1.. This problem arises in the areas of coding theory and information theory.

Comment: @RyanChen Can you state original problem?

Comment: @1.. Briefly speaking, I want to explore the relation between lattice codes and the i.i.d codebook for AWGN channels, in which the later can be approximated by a uniform distribution over some region in $n$-space.

Comment: I think I wrote the previous comment while I was sleeping.